# How do I get attribute3 of attribute2 of attribute1, if attribute2 may or may not exist?

Tags: python, list-comprehension, jira, python-jira

I'm trying to construct a list comprehension to create a list of the value of issues.fields.parent.id, or None if there is no parent.  Is there a simple way of getting attribute2 of attribute1, and returning a default if attribute1 doesn't exist?

```
>> type(issue)
<class 'jira.resources.Issue'>

>> type(issue.fields)
<class 'jira.resources.PropertyHolder'>

>> type(issue.fields.parent)
<class 'jira.resources.Issue'>

>> issues[0].fields.parent.id
'12345'

>> issues[1].fields.parent.id
AttributeError: 'PropertyHolder' object has no attribute 'parent'
```

I want to return the list `['12345', None]`

Trying to pretend the problem doesn't exist obviously returns an error :)

```
>> [i.fields.parent.id for i in issues]
AttributeError: 'PropertyHolder' object has no attribute 'parent'
```

Adding an if statement to the comprehension misses out the None value:

```
>> [i.fields.parent.id for i in issues if hasattr(i.fields, 'parent')]
['12345']
```

Using getattr with a default only returns the value of parent, not parent.id

```
>> [getattr(i.fields, 'parent', None) for i in issues]
[<JIRA Issue: key='PRJ-1', id='12345'>, None]
```

I can do it by creating a function, but six lines of code for one list comprehension seems clunky, and I have quite a few of these to do

```
>>> def parent_id(issue):
...    if hasattr(issue.fields, 'parent'):
...        return issue.fields.parent.id
...    else:
...        return None
>>> [parent_id(i) for i in issues]
['12345', None]
```

Is there a simpler / more elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define something that *has* an `id` attribute of `None` using `types.SimpleNamespace`, and return that from `getattr` instead of `None`.

```
from types import SimpleNamespace
p = SimpleNamespace(id=None)

[getattr(i.fields, 'parent', p).id for i in issues]
```

(`p` is factored out to avoid creating a new instance for every call to `getattr`.)

---

Were PEP 505 to be accepted, you could write something like

```
[getattr(i.fields, 'parent')?.id for i in issues]
```

Comment: I've been wondering how to do something like that for a while but didn't know how to formulate the question!  Thanks, that's perfect.  I'm off to read the docs on SimpleNamespace :)